# Graphviz: label on the left side

Tags: label, orientation, graphviz

in case I use the following Graphviz code, a simple graph will be created
which shows the label on the right hand side.

```
digraph lable_on_the_right_side {

   /* define nodes */

   node [color=lightblue2, style=filled, fontname=Arial];

   a [label="S1"];
   b [label="S2"];


   /* define edges */

   a -> b [label="Label on the right side"]

}
```

[image: Rendered Dot Code as Image]

Is it possible to let the label appear on the left side instead?
If yes, what would the code need to look like?

Comment: It seems to me like changing the position of a label isn't really a good idea. Most of the solutions break as soon as your layout changes. I'd do what I did and just live with it always on the right.

Answer (score 14):

There aren't many ways to change the position of the text of an edge label - you could try to **add some extra empty spaces** to label... Sometimes also **double edges** have the effect of having one label to the right, the other one to the left.

Still hacky, but at least repeatable, you may **use a [`headlabel`](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:headlabel)** (or `taillabel`) and then use [`labelangle`](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labelangle) together with [`labeldistance`](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labeldistance) to position the label where you'd like:

```
a -> b [
        headlabel="Label on the left side" 
        labeldistance=7.5 
        labelangle=75
       ]
```

[image]

With a little trial and error you may place the label where needed.